# How can I accept a hash mark in a URL via $_GET?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, url, segment

From what I have been able to understand, hash marks (#) aren't sent to the server, so it doesn't seem likely that I will be able to use raw PHP to parse data like in the URL below:

```
index.php?name=Ben&address=101 S 10th St Suite #301
```

I'm looking to pre-populate form fields with this $_GET data. How would I do this with Javascript (or jQuery), and is there a fallback that wouldn't break my form for people not using Javascript? Currently if there is a hash (usually in the address field), everything after that is not parsed in or stored in $_GET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode the hash as you should `urlencode`(in php) or `encodeURIComponent`(in JavaScript).

The "hash" is not part of the request, which is why your script never sees it.

Comment: I don't believe this one works. I tried URL /test.php?name=Ben&address=Suite #301 and this code $get = implode($_GET); echo urlencode($get); and it gave me "BenSuite+ "

Comment: @bccarlso - No, you need to encode the URL before you send it. See how @Ben's answer is.

Comment: Gotcha, might not be possible due to this link being generated and sent out in an email, I can't do any encoding in their email, and would probably have a hard time encoding the emails before they get sent out. But now that I know what it would take, it gives me a better understanding, thanks.

Comment: @bccarlso - No problem. Yea you can't do much with the email, other than load a JS page that basically redirects them after encoding the URL

Answer (score 2):

Like webdestroya said, you'll need to send a request with the URL

```
index.php?name=Ben&address=101%20S%2010th%20St%20Suite%20%23301
```

If you're using HTML forms, then the string value will be auto-urlencoded when you submit the form.

Comment: This might be difficult because the user will be clicking a link from an email and will want to see the hash mark rendered in the email, and not show up as %23 or %20, whichever it is. And I can't do any PHP processing in the email.

Answer (score 1):

> the user will be clicking a link from an email and will want to see the hash mark rendered in the email

You need to encode the link to what Ben quoted *before* you stick it in the e-mail. What you currently have is not a URL at all.

You can optionally encode a space to `+` instead of `%20` in the context of query parameters but you absolutely cannot include a raw space, because it is a defining characteristic of URLs that they don't have spaces in. If you type a space in a URL in a web browser it will quietly fix up the mistake, but an e-mail client can't pick out a URL from plain text if it's full of spaces.

There is sometimes an alternative function which encodes spaces to `+` instead of `%20`. Normally this is best avoided as `+` isn't valid in all circumstances, but if prefer:

```
index.php?name=Ben&address=101+S+10th+St+Suite+%23301
```

then you'd use PHP's `urlencode` function instead of the more standard `rawurlencode`.

Either way, you *must* encode the hash to `%23`, because otherwise a hash in an HTTP URL means the fragment identifier (the part of the page to scroll the browser to). This is not part of the address of the page itself; it is not even passed from the browser to the server, so you certainly cannot retrieve it—from `$_GET` or any other interface.

There are many other characters in a component like an address that must be %-encoded before being inserted into a URL string, or they'll leave you with an invalid or otherwise non-functional URL. If all that `%23` business looks funny in a URL... well, you'll have to live with it. That's what URLs have always looked like.

Comment: Thanks. This makes perfect sense to me and you guys have done a great job explaining it. The problem in my specific instance is that I will need to display "Suite #301" in both the email text that the user visibly sees, as well as "Suite #301" (No problem having %23 or Suite+%23301) in the URL, but I wouldn't want the user to see Suite+%23301 in the email. If I had a smart way to generate thousands of emails on the fly, I could probably do this, but I'm limited by that I think. (Unless there is a way to have HTML display HEX-encoded entities… and have it work in email clients.)

Comment: If you're doing HTML mail, you can make the text of the link anything you like, regardless of what the real URL is. But you can't give them the text `#301` at the end of what looks like a link, and expect it to work if they copy-and-paste it into a browser. HTML-encoding is applied over the top and doesn't do anything to help you, though you certainly need it anyway if you're producing HTML mail (otherwise the unencoded `&` in the URL would be an error).

Answer (score 0):

I usually store the hash on a cookie onunload

ej:

```
window.unload = function(){

 if(document.location.hash) setCoockie('myhash',document.location.hash);

};
```